# Reference current terrain height for X/Z in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to create a game in Unity3D in which I will have to spawn numerous objects into the game's world, these objects will be spawned randomly on the X and Z axis however in order to make it so the objects will not be spawned in mid-air or underground, I need to find the current height of the terrain at the X/Z location, so I can instantiate the object at the height level of the terrain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could choose the spot at random on the x and z co-ordinate, but set the y to very high every time. Then raycast down onto the terrain below, and spawn the object at the hit point of the raycast.